# Getting the last item from a Map - a simple solution?

Tags: javascript

I found some answers suggesting iterating through the Map, setting the iterated element to a variable and then reading it after the iteration. But isn't there any better, more elegant view? I could not find a better solution so far.

Comment: Could you show an example of what you want to happen?

Comment: @BlindKai I'm not sure what code to post -  I would like to simply get the last added key/valiue in the Map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the `Map` to an array of entries, then get the last element.

```js
const map = new Map([['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]]);
let lastEntry = [...map].at(-1);
console.log(lastEntry);

// or only get last key/value
let lastKey = [...map.keys()].at(-1);
let lastValue = [...map.values()].at(-1);
console.log(lastKey, lastValue);
```

However, it's more efficient to just iterate over the entries and keep the last one.

```js
const map = new Map([['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]]);
let entry; for (entry of map);
console.log(entry);
```

Comment: I'd expect this to be less efficient than iterating over the entries. It also (probably) wastes linear space.

Comment: Thanks, though I'm a bit confused - in your code I cannot see any conversion to array?

Comment: @JohnV `[...map]` uses spread syntax to convert the `Map` to an array.

Comment: @JohnV The use of an array literal containing the spread operator (`[...<iterator>]`) converts the iterator to an array.

Comment: @Luatic Indeed, it's definitely more performant to just iterate over the entries.

Comment: Ah, thanks, still new to JS syntax.

Comment: @Unmitigated So when iterating through the entries, how to get the last one?

Comment: @JohnV Just like what you mentioned in the question. `let entry; for (entry of map);` At the end of this loop, `entry` is the last entry.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the Map to an array using the `Array.from()` method and then use the array index to access the last item.

```
// Convert Map to an array and get the last item
const myArray = Array.from(myMap);
const lastItem = myArray[myArray.length - 1];

// Log the last item to the console
console.log(lastItem);
```

you can get the last item by accessing the array index `[myArray.length - 1`]

Answer (score 0):

With the built-in `Map` there's no way other than iterating the entries and return what comes last. You can, however, extend `Map` so that it can record its own "history", for example:

```js
class MapWithHistory extends Map {
    history = []

    set(key, val) {
        this.history.push(key)
        return super.set(key, val)
    }
}

m = new MapWithHistory()

m.set('foo', 123)
m.set('bar', 456)
m.set('baz', 789)

lastKey = m.history.at(-1)

console.log(lastKey)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const inputMap = new Map([
  ['k1', 'v1'],
  ['k2', 'v2'],
  ['k3', 'v3']
]);

const lastEntry = [...inputMap.entries()].pop();
console.log(lastEntry);
```

Answer (score 0):

convert a map to the array with spread operator and use `.pop`

```js
const inputMap = new Map([
  ['k1', 'v1'],
  ['k2', 'v2'],
  ['k3', 'v3']
]);

const lastEntry = [...inputMap].pop();
console.log(lastEntry);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. Maps are not an ordered data structure in the sense that they support indexed access - all they have is a deterministic iteration order. If you care about controlling the order of elements or accessing them by index, use an array (possibly in addition to the map).

In terms of elegance, I would recommend a helper function that takes an iterator:

```
function last(iterator) {
  let element;
  for (element of iterator) {}
  return element;
}
```

then call it as

```
last(map.values())
```

or

```
last(map.entries())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the map directly and use a counter from `size` and get the last pair.

```js
const
    map = new Map([['k1', 'v1'], ['k2', 'v2'], ['k3', 'v3'], ['k4', 'v4']]),
    last = [];

let s = map.size;
map.forEach((k, v) => {
    if (!--s) last.push(k, v);
});

console.log(last);
```